# Two different values at the same memory address - assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I have some code in assembly which behaves a little bit strange. I have a C extern function that calls with *asm* another function from an .asm file. This C function puts on the stack three addresses used by my function from .asm file. All went well untill this appeared:

```
; Let's say we take from the stack first parameter from my C function.
; This parameter is a string of bytes that respect this format:
;   - first 4 bytes are the sign representation of a big number
;   - second 4 bytes are the length representation of a big number
;   - following bytes are the actual big number

section .data
  operand1 dd 0

section .text
global main

main:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  mov eax, [ebp + 8] ; Here eax will contain the address where my big number begins.
  lea eax, [eax + 8] ; Here eax will contain the address where 
                     ; my actual big number begins.   
  mov [operand1], eax

  PRINT_STRING "[eax] is: "
  PRINT_HEX 1, [eax] ; a SASM macro which prints a byte as HEX
  NEWLINE

  PRINT_STRING "[operand1] is: "
  PRINT_HEX 1, [operand1]
  NEWLINE 

  leave
  ret
```

When running this code, I get at the terminal the correct output for [eax], and for [operand1] it keeps printing a number which will not change if I modify that first parameter of my C function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the answer to your question as an answer, and mark it as correct. Then the other users can see that the question is solved.

Comment: *calls with *asm* another function from an .asm file*:  What?  You don't need to use inline-asm to call a function defined in a `.asm` file.  Just write a prototype and call it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an understandable mistake. When doing:

```
mov [operand1], eax
PRINT_STRING "[operand1] is: "
PRINT_HEX 1, [operand1]
NEWLINE
```

This code prints the first byte of the content (*which is the address where my actual big number begins*) contained at the address where this local variable (operand1) resides. In order to get the actual value which resides at [operand1] I had to do this:

```
mov ebx, [operand1]
PRINT_STRING "[operand1] is: "
PRINT_HEX 1, [ebx]
NEWLINE
```